# Why did the Hydrogen in Fukushima explode *outside* the reactor vessel?

Tags: nuclear-engineering

As pointed out before, it orginated inside the reactor vessel but exploded outside: how did it get there?  Did it pass the shell by diffusion or was it released by the engineers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They released the steam into the space between the reactor pressure container and the outer wall (sheet metal, deliberately to work as a kind of rupture seal?). Maybe they hoped that some of this substances would condense there when the steam cools down? But because there was a lot of Hydrogen in the steam, explosions blew away the sheet metal.

The reason for the ignition of the hydogen/air mixture is not known. Maybe the temperature of some hot parts of the pressure vessel did that.

**Edit** 
Inside the reactor vessel the hydrogen cannot explode, there is no oxygen available. 
And:
All this was dealt already in two treads. Search for Fukushima.

Comment: What are the reasons for releasing the gas inward the building rather than outwards, needlessly exposing staff to radiation?

Comment: Where do You know from that there was some staff there? Even without radioactivity, from steam (!) alone everybody there would have been killed imediately. Concerning "reason" I wrote a assumption.

Comment: It was just a naive assumption on my part.

Comment: Oh, and thanks, thank you for answering all my questions :-)

Comment: @George @artistoex Engineers released the steam in order to regulate the pressure inside the reactor chamber. See: http://bravenewclimate.com/2011/03/15/fukushima-15-march-summary/

Comment: rkive the question was why the release was directed within the building, not why at all!

Comment: My understanding is that the engineers did not have any way to release the hydrogen outside the reactor building. It doesn't have windows you can open.